# Update an activity by events of a background activity

Tags: android

I have 2 activities A and B. A has a recyclerView with list of songs. When i click one command goes to B and it starts playing it. B has an `onCompletionListener()` so it changes and plays song automatically. When one hovers back to activity A, name of currently playing song is displayed in a textView there. Problem is that when a song is is changed in background, the textView can't be automatically updated.
One solution I had thought is making that textView static and change it from OnCompletionListener in B but I don't find that efficient. Is there a better way of doing that.

Comment: 1. use local broadcast receiver in A. and send broadcast from B on song play. 
OR  
2. start B using startActivityForResult() send some value back to A via onActivityResult() ....

Comment: Supposing you have an unique identifier for each song, the easiest way is to return the last song played ID back to the first activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're newbie in Android, the easiest (and fastest) way to create a communication channel between Android components is using a bus like [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

You just have to create a class containing the informations, then your activities will subscribe to a bus and they will send and receive these objects each other very easily

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to implement this:

- Handler
  You can implement Handler in A and pass the address of Handler to B. And you can send message to A using this Handler.
- BroadcastReceiver
  Same as Handler. You can implement in A and pass the address of BroadcastReceiver to B. And you can send broadcast to B using this.
- startActivityForResult
  You can start activity B by using startActivityForResult. You need to implement onActivityResult function in A. You can send data to A when B is finished. You can send last song data to A when B is finishing.

Comment: Can u tell me how to use a handler here.. I am a newbie in android

Comment: Handler m_handler = new Handler(Looper,getMainLooper()){ public void handleMessage(Message msg){ [your code]}}; You can pass this handler to Activity B and in B, you can send message by using sendMessage(). If you need more ,then i can post another answer with code block.